# Php memory size management

Tags: php

im having some trouble with one of my scripts, basically my scripts updates some products, but since is a lot of products if i dont manage carefully the php memoery from my script i get a error of memoery usage, so basically i used unset to release the memory space, now is much better but is not perfect, so im looking on the php docs and i notice a function called memoery_get_usage() to evaluate my script, i found online a simple example of using this method, but something strange is happening that i cant understand why is giving me this result. Basically i created a variable and store some data using a loop and check the memory between the begginning, after the script finish the loop and than when i unset, but the numbers or not what i expect.

Example script:

```
echo memory_get_usage(). PHP_EOL ;
$a = '';
for($i=0;$i<=100000;$i++){
$a[] = $i;
}
echo memory_get_usage(). PHP_EOL;
unset($a);
echo memory_get_usage(). PHP_EOL;
```

The results are:

```
222048
14871264
222232
```

The strange part is the last numbers, "222232", if i unset the variable, isnt expected to have the initial number memory at the beginning ("222048")?

Hope for someone could explain me.

Comment: Have you unset $i as well? BTW, even in the example from the manual, after unsetting the (only) variable, the output of the memory usage would be bigger than the initial.

Comment: yes i unset $i also

Comment: Even unsetting `$i` you won't get back to the starting amount, as `echo` uses some memory as well.

Comment: but even using echo the memory will not increment, it stays the same, the only strange thing is doesnt get the initial memory

Comment: yes echo need some stack space, but when echo is complete, its freed up, else echo would contain a memory leak! so no, echo aint the problem

Comment: part of it is the residue from the string concatenation (probably happening in some static buffer that is enlarged). replace string concatenation with 2 arguments to echo gives less drastic results on my php 7.0.22